# How can I disable shadowOffset scaling in KonvaJS?

Tags: konvajs, konvajs-reactjs

I am using strokeScaleEnabled=false to disable stroke width scaling. However shadow offset is still scaling when I scale stage. I see no "shadowOffsetScaleEnabled" property to disable shadow offset scaling.

Is there any other API or I must re-calculate shadowOffset values based on stage scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently with `konva@4.1.5` there is no API for disabling shadow offset scaling.

So you have to reset it manually. With something like:

```js
const OFFSET = 5;

shape.shadowOffsetX(OFFSET / stage.scaleX());
shape.shadowOffsetY(OFFSET / stage.scaleY());
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/bikiwedero/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks. I finally did the same. I hope we can have two different layers and apply the scaling to layers instead of stage. So, application chrome can alway be at scale=1. is that possible?

Comment: something like this: `shape.shadowOffsetX(OFFSET / shape.getAbsoluteScale().x);`